# Disclosing node in ADF Tree

Tags: jsf, tree, oracle-adf

I'm using the af:tree ADF component in a jsff page. The model used in the af:tree is a class like this (this class is not based on a ViewObject):

```
public class TreeItem {
  String description;
  List<TreeItem> children;
}
```

How can I disclose nodes that match only some descriptions? In the web I've found only examples with af:tree model based on a ViewObject.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are not using ADF BC. You will have to manage the disclosedRowKeys of the TreeTable and then in the handler for rowDisclosureListener you can update the disclosedRowKeys depending on whether the description matches the requirement. The contents of disclosedRowKeys is the instance of RowKeySet.

```
<af:treeTable disclosedRowKeys="#{myBean.disclosedRowKeys}" 
              rowDisclosureListener="#{myViewBean.handleRowDisclosure}">
</af:treeTable>
```

In the bean:

```
class MyPageBean{
  RowKeySet disclosedRowKeys;
  //getters and setters.
}
```

and in the view bean:

```
class MyViewBean{
  public void handleRowDisclosure(RowDisclosureEvent event)
  {
    //get the addedSet OR removedSet - because the event can be expanding or collapsing row.
    //obtain the collection model from the tree table.
    //use the above collection model and the addedSet OR removedSet to get the exact instance of TreeItem.
    if TreeItem.description is satisfied then
      getDisclosedRowKeys from the page model and then add/remove the keys obtained in the addedSet OR removedSet.

    partially refresh the treeTable.
  }
}
```

I am currently unable to try out this logic. But will give it a try once I am back at work.

Comment: How can I set the content of "#{myBean.disclosedRowKeys}" when a node is an instance of the class TreeItem? Thanks

Comment: The contents of the RowKey is the index i.e the index of the data in the tree table. You can read more about it in one of my blog posts: http://blog.sanaulla.info/2013/05/13/understanding-rowkeyindex-values-in-adf-treetable/
So it doesn't matter whether your node is an instance of TreeItem class or some other class. In anycase you will wrap your List of TreeItem with a ChildPropertyTreeModel instance.

Answer (score 0):

Disclosing a tree node is depending on the tree component itself not on it's model, if you want to disclose it programatically refer to [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/how_to_programmatically_disclose_a) which explain exactly that